# C# Deserialize JSON with chars '/' using JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: c#, json

I've got such JSON string:

```
 "[{\"macId\":\"ttsh\",\"modelNumber\":\"tshf\"},{\"macId\":\"dtgstr\",\"modelNumber\":\"drtgsdsrtg\"}]"
```

I want to Deserialize it. What I'm doing:

```
    private static IList<HandsetModel> handsetsList = new List<HandsetModel>();
    handsetsList = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<HandsetModel>>(handsetsJson);

public sealed class HandsetModel
{
    public string macId { get; set; }

    public string modelNumber { get; set; }
}
```

What I've tryed to do with string:

```
handsetsJson = handsetsJson.Replace(@"\", "");
```

But this line didn't help me. May anybody help?

Comment: I don't think you get that string, that is how the Visual Studio debugger displays strings... can you explain the actual problem?

Comment: List after deserialize is empty

Comment: `var  handsetsList = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<HandsetModel>>("[{\"macId\":\"ttsh\",\"modelNumber\":\"tshf\"},{\"macId\":\"dtgstr\",\"modelNumber\":\"drtgsdsrtg\"}]");` returns a list of 2 for me.

Answer (score 0):

From memory, I believe there are several things you can do to clean this up:

One route is something like:

```
 public static string CleanAllWhiteSpace(string messyJson)
        {
            return (Regex.Replace(messyJson, @"(\s)+|(\n)+|(\r)+|(\t)+", ""));
        }

        public static string removeEscapedQuotes(string escapedString)
        {
            return (Regex.Replace(escapedString, "\\\"", "\""));
        }
```

Another thought, again from memory is use NewtonSoft.JSON instead of the .NET native implementation as it seems like it serialized/ deserialized more cleanly/ predictably.

For example with NewtonSoft's:

```
string serial = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(s).ToString();
```

I get a nice clean:

[image]

Comment: but this would only be needed if the json is invalid, right?

Comment: Not sure I follow, the first would clean up a string that represents a JSON (Like your sample JSON) and the Second would serialize a class into a string that looks like a good JSON...?

Comment: I'm not the OP.... if JSON is valid why would you need to clean it up before deserializing?

Comment: @rene sorry :)
Yes, you are right. In fact, I also flipped what he wanted. That String he shows is a JSON "Object" essentially and *would* deserialize properly at a glace. Cleaning it up for presentation or interop however is sort of what I was hinting at (For example showing in a return string in a browser). Finally, I really wanted to leave a comment with rough ideas but had a few concerns with taking anything else out... (If any of that makes sense)

Comment: Now your answer makes some sense.. ;) I'll check back later to see if the OP did find the root case of the issue.